# Zend gdata Framework Google Docs - Outdated filetypes Need a fix

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

This framework is **outdated** and doesn't support **all kind of files** to upload, so i decided to fix the framework.

In the **class Zend_Gdata_Docs**

I did this by adding the entry JPG/JPEG/PPTX

```
private static $SUPPORTED_FILETYPES = array(
      'JPG'=>'image/jpeg',
      'JPEG'=>'image/jpeg',
      'TXT'=>'text/plain',
      'CSV'=>'text/csv',
      'TSV'=>'text/tab-separated-values',
      'TAB'=>'text/tab-separated-values',
      'HTML'=>'text/html',
      'HTM'=>'text/html',
      'DOC'=>'application/msword',
      'ODS'=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
      'ODT'=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
      'RTF'=>'application/rtf',
      'SXW'=>'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer',
      'XLS'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
      'XLSX'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
      'PPT'=>'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
      'PPTX'=>'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
      'PPS'=>'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
```

It's working fine for the .pptx and for the jpeg/jpg the upload is working completely fine but once in Google Docs it is showing like a doc...

There:

[image: Imge Google Docs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are being converted into the Google Docs native format, to upload them as files, you have to append ?convert=false to the upload uri:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_drawings

Comment: Thanks claudio I'm gonna try this tomorrow I keep you updated ;)

Comment: I try to do something like this:
$entryFile = $docs->uploadFile($fileToUpload, $file->getName(), null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI.'?convert=false');

But then i got "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 501 The field convert is not supported in this request version."

Comment: I should check the library source, but I guess it is sending requests to version 2.0 of the Documents List API. Can you try adding "&v=3" to the url in order to specify version 3.0 of the API?

Comment: Then i got a 404, i think the Zend Framework is doing something with the url in the back-end